# Optimize selection based on two variables

Tags: python, dataframe, mathematical-optimization

I have a pandas df made up of positive integers that looks like this:

```
id    val1   val2
1     10     1
2     1      10
3     5      5
```

I am trying to find the best way I can select the row that maximizes the values in both val1 and val2. Is there a particular algorithm someone can recommend? I am currently just selecting based on the max product of the two values. But is there a better way?

Comment: Can you select multiple rows?  If you can, then I'll tell you all about Pareto optimality.  Otherwise you're stuck with picking an aggregation function:  you can take the sum, you can take the product, you can pick whichever is bigger, whichever is smaller...

Comment: ya i can select multiple rows!

Answer (score 0):

So a row is Pareto optimal when it can't be improved in both criteria at the same time.  In your example, all three rows are Pareto optimal.  The following rows would be dominated:

```
1  1 (by all of the above rows)
1  7 (by 1, 10)
7  1 (by 10, 1)
3  3 (by 5, 5)
```

The way you filter Pareto optimal rows is:

1. Create an empty list of pareto optimal rows
2. Compare each row to your current list of pareto optimal rows.  Any row it dominates should be removed.  If it is not dominated by any row in the current list, add it to the list of pareto optimal rows.